# Computed Field display only if below 0

Tags: entities

In my computed field I'm trying to make it display the field and it's label only if the value is negative.  If it is above 0 it should not display anything, not even field label.

So far in "Display Code (PHP)" I have:

```
if $entity_field_item['value'] < '0' { ;
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'] . '%';
}else{$display_output = ''};
```

But it just returns the label with no value.

The classic

```
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'] . '%';
```

works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($entity_field_item['value'] != 0)
 {
 $display_output = $entity_field_item['value'] . 'pkt';
 }
 else($display_output = NULL);
```

Comment: OP wants a display of the value is lower then 0. Your code also works if the value is higher then 0.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I can see is in the if condition `$entity_field_item['value'] < '0'`

You should remove the quotes from `$entity_field_item['value'] < 0` this should make the if condition as expected. But the Label would still be visible.

To remove that you would need to use the patch from the below link

https://drupal.org/node/1928178

Comment: Thanks. I tried $entity_field_item['value'] < 0 without ' ' and the result is all the same.
Maybe I need to add something in the "Computed Code" field, rather than "Display Code" field?
Also, that patch is for those that don't store in DB.  I do.